# Putting a matrix of undefined length through a function

Tags: matlab

For an exercise I have to do I have to manually make a MATLAB filter much like `imshow`. I have made the following formula:

```
if(picture2<w)
    picture3 = (picture2-b)*heaviside((picture2-b)/w))*heaviside(1-(picture2/w));
else
    picture3 = 1;
end
```

Where `picture2` is the value of a certain pixel (a matrix of in this case 360x331), `b` is the lowest value that should be black and `w` is the width of the area i want the grayscaling to happen to. `picture3` would be the new matrix with altered greyscaling.

If I manually enter values into this formula I receive values that are correct, however I am not able to push the entire matrix through the formula and get a complete new matrix with altered value. Is there a way to easily do this?

Comment: Give more info. What's t and x? What specific error are you encountering? What do you mean by you're not able to push the entire matrix through? Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: Hey sorry for the bad question, ill try to rephrase the question. I have a picture, which has 360x331 values which i need to recalculate using my own formula. t has to be picture2 and x should be w (ill edit this in the main question). and i would like to have every individual value from picture2 be pushed through the formula with as result a new matrix with the new values

Answer (score 1):

#### Analysis

Matlab/Octave provide vectorized expression for what you want to do.

#### Solution

The following code should do what you intend.

```
% Create an image with all 1 and same size as input
picture3 = ones(size(picture2));

% find pixels that are below w
ltw =  picture2<w;

% Process all pixels <w
picture3(ltw) = (picture2(ltw)-b) .* heaviside((picture2(ltw)-b) ./ w)) .* heaviside(1-(picture2(ltw) ./ w));
```

#### Explanation

One trick is creating a `logical` matrix `ltw` containing 1 or true for each pixel fulfilling the condition `>w`. The logical matrix `ltw`is then used to address all pixels matching your condition.

The other trick is to use element wise multiplication and division with the operators `.*` and `./`.  If you multiply two matrices/arrays using the `*` operator this is a *mathematical matrix multiplication*. If you apply the `.*` operator an internal loop is processing the array element by element.

Comment: Please don't introduce the Octave tags randomly in MATLAB questions. If the OP doesn't  mention Octave in his post or anywhere, the tag is irrelevant. This can lead to solutions that may work in Octave but not MATLAB.

Comment: @Sardar: I am carefully looking for topics with a high compatibility and relevance to both languages like in this question before introducing a new tag. Users of both languages can profit from the answers and the question becomes more visible.

Comment: You're just destroying the questions. Just because you added an answer that works on both platforms, doesn't mean that everybody will.

Comment: @SardarUsama: Sorry I can not follow your arguments. What are you talking about?

Comment: That Octave and MATLAB are not always one to one compatible

Comment: @SardarUsama: Yes. That is  exactly what I wanted to say with my first answer above. If it is not compatible it does not make sens to have both tags. In this case the question and solution work on both platforms.

Comment: By adding an irrelevant tag, you're opening the question for irrelevant solutions. And as I said before, just because you added a compatible answer, it is not necessary that everybody will do that too. The answer is meant to be posted according to the tag in the question. Not the otherwise.

Comment: Whether a solution *can* work is irrelevant to the question. If I happen to produce a bit of C code which happens to run in Java, I should not tag the question Java as well. It's what the OP needs. If you tag the question also Octave, even though that's totally unrelated to what the OP wants, a new answerer will think their answer has to be Octave compatible, whilst it doesn't need to be. So please, don't add language tags to questions just because *your* solution happens to be working in both.